# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable for loading a shared library at runtime (g++)

Tags: g++, environment-variables, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I'm having two problems related to the same issue:

1. I have a shared object saved in `pwd`/lib and while the executable that uses it compiles successfully (by using -l and -L switches), at runtime, it's giving me grief. If I try to run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/absolute/path/to/library/directory ./test` it works fine. But if I export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/absolute/path/to/library/directory and do `./test` it says that it can't find the shared library. However, if I do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./test` again it works fine!! Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
2. Second issue is related to the exporting of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable. If I open a terminal and type `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/stuff` and then type `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the variable is correct. However if I write a script containing the export command, simply running it doesn't update the variable, instead I need to run `source install.sh` in order to actually persist the variable. What's the best solution for this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the **second** question first:

`source` executes the script inside the current shell, `./install.sh` opens and executes it in a different shell.
http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/537-difference-between-source-exec-script.html

Now for your first question:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./test` sets the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable before just one command (the `./test` command). For the same reason above, I believe this isn't getting transferred to whatever shell `./test` creates. To make it persist, you may need to put the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to find a way to setup the path to the shared objects without using sudo commands (and put it in /usr/local/lib) or changing user's bash file. Is there a generally accepted way of doing it?

Comment: Hmm, I think there's no "safe" way to do it, but look here: (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-set-ld_library_path-684799/).

I don't know too much about this but I've seen recommendations to wrap your main program in a simple script that sets the library path, runs your actual program and then unsets it. Instead of calling your program directly, users should run the script.

Comment: Actually, this may help: http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/tools/ccs_linkedit_dynamic_dirsearch.html  It is about the LD_RUN_PATH variable, which allows you to specify your library locations at link-time (an alternative to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which "lets you do the same thing at run time"). This is about the limit of my knowledge on this, sorry ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with the script then. The LD_RUN_PATH is for compile time afaik, and that's already taken care of with -L.

Answer (score 2):

I have found sometimes adding -L explicitly via the CFLAGS environment variable is successful when LD_RUN_PATH was not. As in:
export CFLAGS=-L/opt/tool/lib