# Overcome DLL Hell with Code::Blocks

Tags: c, linux, dll, shared-libraries, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks for a project. I have not used an IDE on Linux in years, so I'm a bit out of touch with Linux IDEs.

I'm working with an OpenSSL project that uses FIPS validated library. I duplicated the GCC compiler toolchain and modified it to use OpenSSL's `fipsld` (and set it as default).

When the project's code executes under Code::Blocks via <kbd>F8</kbd>, `FIPS_mode_set` fails with error 252104805 (0xF06D065). 0xF06D065 is:

```
$ openssl errstr 0xF06D065
error:0F06D065:common libcrypto routines:FIPS_mode_set:fips mode not supported
```

which tells me Code::Blocks is not using the OpenSSL I specified in `/usr/local/ssl/lib`. Rather, the program is using the non-FIPS library provided by Debian in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

An image of the link library settings is below. Note that the libraries are fully specified, and nothing is left to chance.

[image: Code::Blocks link library settings]

CodeBlocks is clearly doing things with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (shown below).

[image: LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings]

I've also verified the project is using the correct search directories - `/usr/local/ssl/include` for headers and `/usr/local/ssl/lib` for the linker.

With compiler logging set to "Full Command Line" set, here's what I get from the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in ac ---------------

Compiling: main.cpp
/home/jwalton/Desktop/ac/main.cpp:8:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
/home/jwalton/Desktop/ac/main.cpp:8:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
Linking console executable: bin/Debug/ac
Output size is 569.67 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 2 warnings
```

I'm aware of Basile Starynkevitch's suggestions on `rpath`'s and `LD_PRELOAD` tricks, but this seems like one of those things the IDE should be handling for me (Visual Studio will handle it properly, and even gives us an input box to [set Working Directories to find additional libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119539/visual-studio-how-to-set-path-to-dll)).

Any ideas how to make Code::Blocks use the shared objects in `/usr/local/ssl/lib` when executing the program under the debugger?

Comment: Please post full build log from CodeBlocks. Set "show full command line" option for this: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=662.0

Answer (score 3):

Your IDE instructs the compiler to link against the specified libraries, *but not to load them at run time*. For this latter thing to happen, you need to pass another option to the linker, namely

```
-rpath=/path/to/directory/with/your/libraries
```

or, if the linker is invoked by the compiler,

```
-Wl,-rpath=/same/thing
```

Comment: Thanks n.m. I'm running this under Code::Blocks via <kbd>F8</kbd>. So Code::Blocks does not handle things so they "just work" like Visual Studio? Sorry to ask. I have not worked in a Linux IDE in years.

Comment: It's not Code::Blocks vs Visual Studio. It's Unix vs Windows. They are not the same. Learn them, love them.

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) don't use [shared objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) ([DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) are a Windows thing). Because `Code::Blocks` is simply an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). IDEs are glorified [source code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) with the ability to run *external* [software development tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_tools). You could (and sometimes you should, at least to learn how things happen) edit your code with a plain good editor like `emacs`, and build it with commands. Your IDE is just running commands, notably a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and a [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), probably using `gcc`

So what is using shared objects in `/usr/local/ssl/lib/` is the compiler and linker (and the runtime [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linking)). BTW, `/usr/local/ssl/lib/` is a *very* strange name for a directory containing shared objects; you should have configured *OpenSSL* to be installed in `/usr/local/lib/` !

First, I really believe you should reconfigure and recompile and rebuild and reinstall your SSL to get it installed under `/usr/local/` (or perhaps `/opt/`) prefix (i.e. shared libraries in `/usr/local/lib`).

Then you could add appropriate options for the [`ld` linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/index.html) (from `binutils`). You probably want `-L/usr/local/ssl/lib` (to the `gcc` command which is running `ld`), and you may want to pass `-Wl,-rpath` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8027971/841108)).

I would suggest to reinstall your SSL in `/usr/local/`, add `/usr/local/lib/` into `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or at least into your [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15729137/841108)...) and run `ldconfig`

Otherwise, add at least `/usr/local/ssl/lib/` in front of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  (and also `-L/usr/local/ssl/lib/` to your linking command).

Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5130654/841108), and **Drepper's [How To Write Shared libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper**.

Comment: Thnaks Basile. "... edit your code with a plain good editor like emacs, and build it with commands" - that's normally what I do on Linux because the IDEs have been so much trouble in the past (Visual Studio is so nice, its hard to accept less). I even write my makefiles by hand on Linux. I was hoping the IDE's auto-complete would speed up development since I despise grepping OpenSSL source files for function names.

Comment: No, IDEs are slowing down development, because they are *hiding* things. Maybe you want [ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) or `etags` (with `emacs`)?

Comment: Thanks again Basile. "you should have configured OpenSSL to be installed in `/usr/local/lib/`" - you have to be careful of doing things like this when working with the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module. If one diverges from procedure, it invalidates the the validation. Setting a directory during `config` would be such a violation.

Comment: Then use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `-Wl,-rpath` tricks mentioned in my answer (and accept it if it fits).

Answer (score 0):

Just open the terminal and type

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/libraries 
sudo ldconfig
```